# Can someone explain what "background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;" is doing?

Tags: css

I've been using this method

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

With this as my css for the div.

```
    mydiv {
            background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
    }
```

I don't understand what this part is. Which css properties is it filling in?

```
    center center;
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: It helps more about background: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will understand it better, if you split your background properties into:

```
background-image:url('images/bg.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to see.

Answer (score 3):

no-repeat means the background image will display once.

```
center center
```

means that the image will be centered both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Which css properties is that filling in?

Comment: MillaresRoo answered that one sufficiently above :)